# Resizable Multidimensional table

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lua, coronasdk

I need to store a board containing `true` or `false` value fields, and then also be able to check the value of those fields. Of course I may create a separate class containing row and column and store every single field in a list and then check if there's an entry containing desired coordinates, but it's not an optimal way.

In Lua I used to do it like this:

```
local storedTab = {}

local function setValue(row, column)
    if not storedTab[row] then storedTab[row] = {} end
    storedTab[row][column] = true
end

local function getValue(row, column)
    return storedTab[row] and storedTab[row][column]
end
```

So once an row entry was made, i was adding only a column entries to an already created tab. It was most optimal, I think.

Edit: So how to make it using C#?
Edit2: Board will grow during a gameplay. And will stop after you die. So there's no way to know any dimension of array to initialize it.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: :) Right. I'm asking how to best store it using C#

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's multiple approaches to make 2D arrays but it depends if they're jagged or not (jagged meaning each row can have varying number of columns); `bool[,]` vs `bool[][]`, and if you've got a situation where you know the number of rows/columns when creating the array or not.

Comment: As far as I noticed, there's no way to create (jagged or not) array when you don't know any of, rows or columns amount. Am I right?

Comment: If you know neither, a list of lists would be the simple route; that would be very similar to your Lua approach. i.e. a `new List<List<bool>>();` - this wouldn't be my personal choice though. However, is the board always square? (3x3, 4x4, 5x5 etc?)

Comment: No. It is almost never a square. There's usually much difference between columns and rows amount, depending on which direction hero follows.

Comment: Riighht ok, that changes things a lot - if it was square, my personal choice would be to use the answer below, but if it isn't then you certainly don't want to. So this is the gameworld with a ["fog of war"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog_of_war#In_video_games)?

Comment: In short, lists and arrays are _probably_ the wrong approach for that, but it depends on a) where the "visited" tile information comes from (procedural?) and b) how big the gameworld can actually get (no limit?).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

The original question did not mention that the array is expected to grow over time. Array does **not** grow. It is a fixed size once created.

Although, you can create a new array size and copy old values from the other array to it but I wouldn't recommend this since there are other solutions.

You can use `List<List<bool>>` for this. It is very tricky but can be done with a simple wrapper.

```
public class BoolArray
{
    List<List<bool>> storedTab;

    public BoolArray(int newRowSize = 1, int newColumnSize = 1, bool defaultValue = false)
    {
        storedTab = new List<List<bool>>();
        reSize(newRowSize, newColumnSize, defaultValue);
    }

    //Grows by 5 as default
    public void reSize(int newRowSize = 5, int newColumnSize = 5, bool defaultValue = false)
    {
        //Fixes problem when newRowSize is 0
        if (newRowSize <= 0)
        {
            //Add/Increment Column to every row
            int allRow = storedTab.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < allRow; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < newColumnSize; j++)
                {
                    storedTab[i].Add(defaultValue);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newRowSize; i++)
            {
                //Resize Row
                storedTab.Add(new List<bool>());


                //Resize Column
                for (int j = 0; j < newColumnSize; j++)
                {
                    storedTab[i].Add(defaultValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int row, int column, bool value)
    {
        storedTab[row][column] = value;
    }

    public bool getValue(int row, int column)
    {
        return storedTab[row][column];
    }

    public int rowSize
    {
        get { return storedTab.Count; }
    }

    public int columSize
    {
        get
        {
            return storedTab[0].Count;
        }
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columSize; j++)
            {
                storedTab[j].Clear();
            }
        }
        storedTab.Clear();
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
BoolArray boolArray = new BoolArray(1, 1);

//Set Value
boolArray.setValue(0, 0, true);

Debug.Log("Before Row Size: " + boolArray.rowSize);
Debug.Log("Before Column Size: " + boolArray.columSize);

//Resize by 4 and 6 (now 5 by 7)
boolArray.reSize(4, 6);

Debug.Log("After Row Size: " + boolArray.rowSize);
Debug.Log("After Column Size: " + boolArray.columSize);

//Resize by 10 and 20 (now 15 by 27)
boolArray.reSize(10, 20);

Debug.Log("After Row Size: " + boolArray.rowSize);
Debug.Log("After Column Size: " + boolArray.columSize);

//Get Value
Debug.Log("Value: " + boolArray.getValue(0, 0));

boolArray.clear();
```

Comment: That's quite a good solution. But I'll never know the max dimensions of the board. So I cannot provide the size of an array.

Comment: In that case, Check my Edit

Comment: I meant my board will grow during a gameplay. And will stop after you die. Of course there will be an reasonable amount of rows and columns (f.ex. 800, 800), but I'd like to avoid initializing such a giant array every round, if most players will die achieving 50 - 100 size at most.

Comment: Three things to tell you. **1**.You did not mention this in your question. **2**.Array does no grow. Once created, array is a fixed size. **3**.You can use the code in my answer then add a function that will create new array, copy the old array(`storedTab` ) value to the new one then override `storedTab` array with that new array.It's not complicated. Just try to do it yourself.

Comment: 1. Yeah, my bad. 3. Wouldn't it affect performance too much? I thought about this solution, but dropped it thinking it will consume too much of resources.

Comment: Yes, that will affect performance. Look at the modified answer. Please make sure to be clear in your question next time. Had to change code 3x.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `HashTable`

```
Hashtable storedTab = new Hashtable();

//Add a value
storedTab[row+"-"+column] = true;   //create a unique key like "1-3" (for row 1, column 3)

//To check if this row/column has a value
if (storedTab.ContainsKey(row+"-"+column))
{
   //do something with storedTab[row+"-"+column]
}
```

Comment: Hashtable is very old and slow but it that works for you then go for it.